# How to Change a Plugin's CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I have installed a plugin in wordpress that creates image thumbnails and displays links for all the subpages of a particular page. It is being displayed on the front page of [this website](http://cbchaverhill.onedirectionconnection.com).

The plugin is called AutoNav. More info [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/autonav/).

The plugin FAQ says the following about what classes are created to create the table:

```
table elements: subpages-table
tr elements: subpages-row
td elements: subpages-cell
p elements inside each td: subpages-text
Thumbnail images: subpages-image
Excerpt text: subpages-excerpt
```

My question is how I should go about formatting my CSS to change these settings. Should I just create classes with those names?

Lastly, the links that the plugin generates work on initial page load, but once the page completely loads, the links seem to stop working and just become text. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how I should go about formatting my CSS to change these
>   settings. Should I just create classes with those names?

Yes.  These are the classes the plugin generates and applies to the elements in the html.

For example if you wanted to add a border to the thumbnail images you would apply the styles to `.subpage-image` class.

```
.subpage-image {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

> Lastly, the links that the plugin generates work on initial page load,
>   but once the page completely loads, the links seem to stop working and
>   just become text. Not sure what the issue is.

This is being caused by your slider.  Once it is fully loaded the div #slider overlays your content making the links unclickable.

To fix this give `#slider` height:280px;

Comment: I noticed this about the Slider DIV extending all the way to the bottom of the page, but the thing is, I don;t have a "slider" class or ID, at least not actually defined in my CSS. If I define it, and assign it a height, will it still fix the issue?

Comment: Scratch that, I figured it out! It was in the "nivoslider" class. I defined the height and everything works again!

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Yes it will.  Alternatively you could apply the height to the nivoSlider class.

Comment: Thanks Jrod! I appreciate your help! Everything is working now!

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help.  Good luck with the rest of your project.